# Encrypt with AES256 using CommonCrypto, decrypt using OpenSSL or Java

Tags: java, objective-c, openssl

I am working on an iOS Mobile application. The application data was encrypted using CommonCrypto and `AESCrypt`. I can decrypt it with:

```
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath: filePath];  function, and then the resulted NSData is passed for encryption to following function. 
- (NSData *) AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;
```

I am not able to decrypt the application data using any other tool. I am trying to decrypt it using OpenSSL, but i always get some errors like ***`bad magic numbers`***, ***`bad decrypt`***, etc.

Also I am struggling with modes: CBC, ECB, PKCS7 etc. My code works only if I use PKCS7, other wise the final `NSData` returned is nil, It is not working even inside objective-c.

Comment: "Not able to decrypt" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Where is the OpenSSL code?

Comment: I am running commands on termina -l openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -K F7C24821F67C53A0F4E5B7EE28056220F439D31A6B7750E1554FA9CD828103AC -iv 2AD6C171834BC5EC272DDE0D55ED438D -in a.txt -out d.txt

Comment: Encryption/Decryption returns nil means there's something wrong with it. Please provide with more error code (such as -4303 alignment error, etc.) so we can help you out!